How to do I make child gradle project inherit dependencies and exclusions from parent project?
I am trying to create a project with Gradle and Spring Boot, which will have dependencies and exclusions that should be inherited by any child project that implements it.
I am using a Kotlin DSL build.gradle.kts file in both parent and child projects.
Specifically, my parent project (Project A) has this:
configurations {
    all {
        exclude(group = "org.springframework.boot", module = "spring-boot-starter-logging")
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2")
} 

I want any projects that use Project A as a dependency to also include these dependencies (which is not an issue) and the exclusions as well.
Point to note here, the excluded dependency is a transitive dependency of spring-boot-starter. But spring-boot-starter will be in the dependency list of my child project as well, which is why I want the exclusion to carry over.
I tried looking into this issue, found an article where this can be done using dependencyManagement in Maven. (Link to article)
So I tried finding an equivalent of this in Gradle, found the dependencyManagement function, but I have no idea about the syntax or how to use it.
In the current state, adding Project A as a dependency in a child project resolves all dependencies properly but does not do the exclusion.
